# how do call function in windows asm

Tags: assembly

### how do call this call,function has parameters, i don't know call,

```
00EC17E7    68 347BEC00     push Project2.00EC7B34                   ;                                                -----------------------------------------------
00EC17EC    E8 48FBFFFF     call Project2.00EC1339
00EC17F1    83C4 04         add esp,0x4                              ;esp是栈指针
00EC17F4    8BF4            mov esi,esp
00EC17F6    6A 04           push 0x4
00EC17F8    68 707BEC00     push Project2.00EC7B70                   ; 参数1：标题提示
00EC17FD    68 7C7BEC00     push Project2.00EC7B7C                   ; 参数2：是否
00EC1802    6A 00           push 0x0                                 ; 参数3：0
00EC1804    FF15 98B0EC00   call dword ptr ds:[<&USER32.MessageBoxA>>; 函数调用：USER32.MessageBoxA
00EC180A    3BF4            cmp esi,esp                              ; true
00EC180C    E8 1BF9FFFF     call Project2.00EC112C
00EC1811    68 347BEC00     push Project2.00EC7B34                   ; -----------------------------------------------
```

#### How call this function call

### why show error ,thanks master.

```
mov esp,00FCFB54
add esp,0x4
mov esi,esp
push 0x4
push 0x00EC7B70
push 0x00EC7B7C
push 0x0
call 0xECB098
cmp esi,esp
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ASM call game function

Answer (score 0):

depends on the processor you are using
for a caller function before you call another callee function you can either do 2 things

1- copy parameters to the stack and the callee will get it from the ram. (x86).

2- pass those parameters in the CPU registers themselves (x86 64 bit)